# Is there a way to find a unique internal name in a SPFieldCollection without a try catch?

Tags: spfield, internal-name

The method `SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName` throws an error if it can't find the field with the given the internal name.

Is there a way to determine if a field with an internal name exists without throwing an error?

I created this but I don't like throwing errors for every field I am dealing with.

```
public string UniqueInternalName(string initialInternalName, SPFieldCollection fieldCollection)
{
    string uniqueInternalName = initialInternalName;
    int? internalNameCount = null;

    try
    {
        if (fieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(initialInternalName) != null)                
            internalNameCount = 0;

        while (fieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(uniqueInternalName) != null)
            uniqueInternalName = initialInternalName + internalNameCount++;
    }
    catch { }

    return uniqueInternalName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is is no other way determine if a field with an internal name exists without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TryGetFieldByStaticName method on the SPFieldCollection: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.trygetfieldbystaticname(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.trygetfieldbystaticname%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Returns null if nothing is found.

Comment: -1 The StaticName != (is not equal to) InternalName. Most of the time it is but sometimes it isn't. "...the values returned by the StaticName and InternalName properties can be different. Note that you can set the StaticName property whereas the InternalName property is read-only." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.staticname.aspx

Comment: Sure, it can be different, but most of the time it isn't.  That's the only method provided that doesn't error if the field doesn't exist.  Your other option is to iterate through each field in the collection until you find a match.

Comment: It isn't even looking up the right field property. Most of the time just isn't acceptable. I hope my e-commerce site built in SharePoint is mostly secure? No.